# Using CaptiveNetwork to authenticate wifi network

Tags: ios, captivenetwork

I am trying to use the CaptiveNetwork api to have my app authenticate with known wifi networks.  I am able to register my app with `CNSetSupportedSSIDs`, which prevents the os from displaying a web sheet.  However, there is little documentation, indeed little information anywhere, it seems, on how my app is notified once a connection is established to a registered network.  Perhaps I am missing something?

If anyone has any advice on where to look, or knows of apps that perform wifi authentication, so I can examine their use-case, or spots something that I've obviously missed, do let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you been able to do it.